# CallKit CXEndCallAction report to other end - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, callkit, cxprovider

I am implementing Apple CallKit for VOIP.
I could successfully show the call screens.

On Answer trigger the below function,

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction){
}
```

Ans When reject the call triggered the function,

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXEndCallAction){
}
```

But, How to know on received side when the sender disconnected call (Not accepted the call).

Comment: CallKit is all about UI and controls. It doesn't provide any business rules about actions of the receiver. You should use external systems such as WebRTC ou Twilio to let you know about these kind of events.

Answer (score 3):

- Brother Callkit is basically a Native UI which you can show up when
  device receives/starts a VOIP call its only for user interaction, by using
  it you cannot tell other side about call.
- You have to make socket emitter which will be emitted in
  'CXEndCallAction' method to your server, then your server will inform
  other side.